# Issue with messagebundle.properties in SAP UI 5

Tags: javascript, web, asp.net-core, sapui5

I am fairly new to SAP UI 5 and am a little confused as to why I am not seeing the correct descriptive text for elements within the framework.

I am using the `sap.m.TableSelectDialog` in my application and have based my work on the example here:

https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/sample/sap.m.sample.TableSelectDialog/preview

In the example you can see the use of the cancel button named 'Cancel'

However in my application the cancel button's name is set to 'MSGBOX_CANCEL'

I understand that the exact description is set in the messagebundle.properties file in a format like:

`MSGBOX_CANCEL=Cancel`

Could anyone point me in the right direction as to why this is not working for me?

I also receive the following error in the console:

[image]

The file is present though.

Cheers,
James

Comment: Have you set the binding correctly to {i18n>MSGBOX_CANCEL} ? Also have you correctly initialized the Resource Bundle ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check you project.json or component.js for proper binding of the resource bundle for i18n files.

Comment: Thanks for this.  I eventually found that the reason this was not working was because my web server was not reading files with an extension of .properties - which explains the 404's in chrome.  I mapped the extension and that fixed it.

Comment: @JamesSherburn could you please advise how did you do that? I am having the same issue and not sure where should I find these extension points?

Answer (score 2):

Your webserver must know a MIME type for *.properties files.
Otherwise those files will not be served and you see a 404 error.

**Examples:**

In **IIS** on Windows you have to open up IIS Manager, click on server name in the left pane, in the middle pane double click the icon "MIME Types", and add File name extension ".properties" with MIME type "text/plain".

In **Apache** you simply open the file /conf/mime.types, look for the line starting with "text/plain", and add "properties" to the end. The result should look similar to this:

```
text/plain txt text conf properties
```